# Cannot change Nameservers to cloudflare

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, cloudflare, ns-record

I have a domain but I can't change its nameservers to point Cloudflare's. I've been told that the NIC is rejecting them (it's a ccTLD), literally "your nameservers are not authoritative for that domain". This domain used to be pointing to CF's nameservers some time ago but now it's using another provider.
Let's say the domain was using old.ns.cloudflare.com as NS some time ago, now it's using ns.othercompany.com and I want it to point to new.ns.cloudflare.com.

If I do a "dig NS mydomain.com" I get "ns.othercompany.com" which is correct.
Now if I try to do "dig @new.ns.cloudflare.com NS mydomain.com" it gives me back "old.ns.cloudflare.com", which I think it's wrong and that could be the reason why the NIC rejects the change.

Am I right to say that a namesever for a certain domain should always return it's own IP/hostname for a NS DNS resolution?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the nameservers CloudFlare indicates?

Comment: 100% sure. In fact, I've tried to do it 3 times already and they always get rejected.

Comment: OK, what is the domain and what are the nameservers you were supposed to use?